# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ')' in ejs file

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>List Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>List Page</h1>
<a href="/insert">INSERT DATA</a>
<hr/>
<table width = "100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>DELETE</td>
        <td>EDIT</td>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Model Number</td>
        <td>Series</td>
    </tr>
    
    <%= data.forEach((item, index) => { %>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/delete/<%= item.id %>">DELETE</a></td>
            <td><a href="/edit/<%= item.id %>">EDIT</a></td>
            <td><%= item.id %></td>
            <td><%= item.name %></td>
            <td><%= item.modelnumber %></td>
            <td><%= item.series %></td>
        </tr>
    <%= }) %>
   
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

> I'm currently having a small problem with syntaxError.  I checked as
> far as i can but i failed. Can you tell me is there some miss typo in
> there?
>
> I wanna show this to website but it doesn't give me a hint.. I really
> have no clue of where is wrong.. Please help me..

Comment: app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('Lists', {
        data : data
    });
}); 

this is a code that loading ejs file! Could you check this?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO, You need to put `data.foreach()` without this ejs tag `<%=` but this ejs tag `<%`. So your code should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>List Page</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>List Page</h1>
<a href="/insert">INSERT DATA</a>
<hr/>
<table width = "100%" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>DELETE</td>
        <td>EDIT</td>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Model Number</td>
        <td>Series</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Here is the first change -->
    <% data.forEach((item, index) => { %>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/delete/<%= item.id %>">DELETE</a></td>
            <td><a href="/edit/<%= item.id %>">EDIT</a></td>
            <td><%= item.id %></td>
            <td><%= item.name %></td>
            <td><%= item.modelnumber %></td>
            <td><%= item.series %></td>
        </tr>
<!-- Here is the second change -->
    <% }) %>
   
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for telling me! But when i removed '=', i get this error

19|         </tr>

    20|         

 >> 21|         <% data.forEach((item, index) => { %>

    22|             <tr>

    23|                 <td><a href="/delete/<%= item.id %>">DELETE</a></td>

    24|                 <td><a href="/edit/<%= item.id %>">EDIT</a></td>


data.forEach is not a function

Comment: Try setting a value to the data variable which would work with foreach(an array)

Comment: I had the same issue but mine was due to using a reserved keyword like the name of the variable. The variable name was `classes`.

Answer (score 0):

You should use <%%> to contain logic code , such as :

```
 <% data.forEach((item, index) => { %>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/delete/<%=item.id%>">DELETE</a></td>
            <td><a href="/edit/<%=item.id%>">EDIT</a></td>
            <td><%=item.id%></td>
            <td><%=item.name%></td>
            <td><%=item.modelnumber%></td>
            <td><%=item.series%></td>
        </tr>
    <% }) %>
```

Comment: i tried that but the error said "data.forEach is not a function".

Comment: You need check `data` variable sent from server . This error said "Your variable is not exist or not iterable". To use `forEach` , `data` must be an array

Comment: i connected my database to data variable.... Is there anything weird about my code except that??

Comment: Can you put breakpoint or print to console your data variable ?

Comment: @LeQuang Oh...i think i connected database in a wrong way... i did like this "var data = `SELECT * FROM products`; " Could you tell me how to connect database?

Comment: You can follow this series to work with SQL : https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mysql.asp

Comment: Thank you so much for this tip but i have to use sequelize... Thanks for your help!! I hope i could find how to...